# Query DevOps by 'when a tag was added'

Tags: azure-devops

I haven't been able to find any information this. I am trying to query Devops so that the 'created/activated date' refers to when a certain tag was added to the work item.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tried to use the "History" to query the changed date, but the "[History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#list-items-based-on-the-contents-of-the-history-field)": Comments entered into the Discussion area are queryable. Change history entries, such as which fields were changed, aren't queryable.  So currently there is no option to get the "created/activated date" refers to when a certain tag was added to the work item.

You could use "[Request a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion)" on the left side of Developer Community to open a new suggestion ticket.